# NodeJS Puppeteer: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror, puppeteer

I've been getting the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null**

This is the element:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[name]" class="form-control" placeholder="Full 
Name*" autocomplete="name" x-autocompletetype="name" 
spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
```

And this is my code (using puppeteer):

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent(userAgents[Math.floor(Math.random()*userAgents.length)]);

  await page.goto('website here');

  await page.evaluate(() => {

    document.querySelector('[placeholder="Full Name*"]').setAttribute('value', 'test');

  });
```

I have also used:

```
document.querySelector('[name="fields[name]"]').setAttribute('value', 'Test');
```

And I have also tried using xpath, all which have failed.

**It is important to note that the querySelector line runs fine in chrome console so I don't know why its not working here...** Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding something like `await page.waitForSelector('[name="fields[name]"]', {timeout: 2000}))` before evaluating `setAttribute` stuff? Maybe element is created a bit later, after initial HTML is loaded.

Comment: @ahwayakchih I just tried implementing that with a 20000 timeout and it just times out so puppeteer clearly cant find the element for some reason...

Comment: maybe try to output HTML that puppeteer receives, just to make sure that `input` element is there?

Comment: Your code is working for me